# RODBC - Query vector longer than 1

Tags: r, odbc

Using `RODBC` you can query a database like this:

```
library(RODBC)

dbHandle <- odbcDriverConnect('driver=SQL Server;server=SOME_SERVER;trusted_connection=true')
returnDf <- sqlQuery(dbHandle, query, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
odbcClose(dbHandle)
```

This assumes that the object `query` is a vector of length 1. What happens if it is not? So, if `query` contains two elements - is the database queried twice?

Comment: I don't use `RODBC`, but in `DBI` it errors. Have you tried it? I'd think `query <- c("select 1 as a", "select 2 as b")` would be simple enough to insert here and answer the question for all of us :-)

Comment: You're totally right. Let me provide the answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @r2evans for pointing out the solution:

```
query <- c("select 1 as a", "select 2 as b")

dbhandle <- odbcDriverConnect('driver=SQL Server;server=SOME_SERVER;database=csn_pricing;trusted_connection=true')
df <- sqlQuery(dbhandle, query, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
odbcClose(dbhandle)
```

This results in

```
> df
  a
1 1
```

Hence, only the first element is used.